# drawing 3D line

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm trying to draw 3D line with c# and openTK but when I run the program nothing happens. Can someone tell me what is missing with the code

```
   GameWindow window = new GameWindow();
   GLControl control = new GLControl();
   GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit |ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
   GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
   GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
   GL.LoadIdentity();
   GL.Begin(BeginMode.Lines);

   GL.Color3(Color.Blue);
   GL.Vertex3(100, 100, 0);
   GL.Vertex3(100, 100, 0);
   GL.End();}
```

Comment: you draw a line from (100,100,0) to (100,100,0). Since you are drawing a line from a point to itself, what do you expect to see? In addition: When setting the projection matrix to identity, the visible area is between [-1,1] on each axis.

Comment: Dear Taw i changed the first point to (50,50,10) and the second point to (100,100,30) and I removed Gl.loadidentity and still nothing happens what should I do ??

Comment: Even if you don't call Gl.loadidentity, projection is an identity matrix by default. Why not trying a line with coordinates between -1 and 1? Or you specify a orthographic projection matrix that fits to your coordinates.

Comment: Dear Taw can you post fro me a code that work along with the references and should i write the code in an "protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)"